# Tracking Users Location

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-location, locationmanager

I have a use case where I need to keep record of Users Location twice a day even app is closed or in background. From android 8 there is a limitation of background services so Initially I have implemented the foreground service to track the users. But showing the app running notification is so annoying.

I am just wondering if anyone has gone through same situation and figures out some smarter way to get uses location in background without foreground or background services. I don't need the frequent location updates. Just couple of locations in a day will be fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you only need a couple of locations a day, then a JobScheduler or AlarmManager set for every few hours that launches a background service to get the location would be sufficient.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for prompt response. Do you know any sample link of those.